# PowerShell- Create html link (href) for each pdf from a directory (folder) of .pdf files

Tags: html, powershell, pdf

I am somewhat new to PowerShell and I have been asked to use PowerShell to add a list (folder) of pdf files to a webpage. I have searched the web over and haven’t had any luck. There has been a few forums and articles that come close but nothing so far that would really help with this specific task.

Purpose: I have separated my html into sections; top, working, bottom. I created a PowerShell script that takes the 3 separate .html files and combines them into one. The goal behind this is to pack the working html file with the all of the pdf files from one folder. The pdf folder is being updated on a daily basis and the script will run on the same timeline.

Normally I would post the code I have but so far it has been miss directed and would probably only make onlookers scratch their head. I do have a feeling I am supposed to use one of these too;

`Select-Object FileName,@{name="Link"; expression={"<a href=""" + $web.Url + "/" + $_.FileName + """>Link</a>"}} | Out-File C:\`

Or

`@{Label="Link";Expression={"<a href='$($_.Value)'>$($_.Name)</a>"}}`

The problem is that I don’t know how to properly use either of these two.

Just pumping it out into an .html file won’t help me make usable links. 
`[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('C:\Users\sample\GPDF','*.PDF')| Out-File C:\sample.html`

Comment: Not posting your actual code makes onlookers scratch their head as well. How would you try to apply one of the `Select-Object` expressions that you found? If you show that, it would be easier to point out, where your mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but here is what might be helpful.

First get the list of pdf files in folder_name directory. Create a expression from the results.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder_Name\" | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".pdf"} | Select-Object @{name="Link"; expression={"a href='$($_.FullName)'>$($_.Name)</a>"}} | Out-File C:\FileName.html

Results
Link                                                                                                                                                                                               
----                                                                                                                                                                                               
a href='C:\Folder_Name\1.pdf'>1.pdf</a>                                                                                                                              
a href='C:\Folder_Name\2.pdf'>2.pdf</a>
```

I am also new to powershell so any feedback to improve this script will be appreciated. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried your code and tkosinski's code, his had the "http." Not sure what that was supposed to do but it didn't work. Your script worked great. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to tweak NepCoder's answer a bit:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder_Name\" | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".pdf"} | 
Select-Object @{name="Link"; expression={"<a href='http://mypath/$($_.Name)'>$($_.Name)</a><br/>"}} | Out-File C:\FileName.html
```